# MySQL Query with multiple columns but exact matches?

Tags: mysql, jquery-ui

I've got my table called Device_tbl which has the following columns:

- Image
- Manufacturer
- Model

An example of some of my Manufacturers are:

- Sony Ericsson
- HTC
- Motorola

An example of some of my Models are:

- One X
- One S
- Xperia Arc
- Xperia X10
- Xoom

The issue I have is that I pass the combination of a Manufacturer and a Model into the query.  For example:

```
SELECT Image, Manufacturer, Model FROM Device_tbl WHERE Manufacturer LIKE 'Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc' OR Model LIKE 'Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc'
```

As you can see, this would return nothing.  What I am after is an it to return an EXACT match of only that result above, however if I searched for Son it'd return all results where Son exists in either Manufacturer or Model.

### Possible solution?

If its any help, I am using the JQuery Autocomplete function to generate the full names.  These suggestions are generated from an array which combines the  Manufacturer and Model.  Not sure if there's a way to split it in the background so the search is more accurate?

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_database_connection, $database_connection);
$query = "SELECT * FROM Device_tbl";
$result=mysql_query($query, $database_connection) or die(mysql_error());
$findrow = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $manufac = $row['Manufacturer'];
    $mod = $row['Model'];
    $string = $manufac.' '.$mod;
    $findrow[] = $string;
}

?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($findrow);?>;

  $("#search_input").watermark("Begin Typing to Search");
  $('#searchresultdata').append(sendSelected);

    $( "#search_input" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function(event, ui) {
          sendSelected(ui.item.value);
          }
        });

function sendSelected(_val){
    var search_input = _val;
    if (search_input =='') search_input ='*';
    var dataString = 'keyword='+search_input;

    if (search_input.length > 2 || search_input=='*') {
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "core/functions/searchdata.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(server_response) {
                $('#searchresultdata').empty();
                $('#searchresultdata').append(server_response);
                $('span#category_title').html(search_input);
            }
        });
    }
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CONCAT_WS() such as

```
SELECT * FROM Device_tbl WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', Manufacturer, Model) = 'Sony EricssonXperia Arc';
```

Comment: Oh... Perfect, didn't realise you could do that. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do it like this:

```
SELECT Image, Manufacturer, Model 
FROM Device_tbl 
WHERE Manufacturer+' '+Model LIKE 'Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc'
```